# How can we simplify this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If we have $x+(x \cdot y)$, is it possible to simplify this, on having only one single x?

How can we make those two X together?

Comment: Rewrite the first $x$ to $x\cdot 1$; then use the distributive law.

Comment: Have you notice the L ? Can you please elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: $x+(x\cdot l)=x\cdot (1+l)$. Also you never want your two x's together.

Comment: I will change the L for y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can "combine like terms".  We have:
$$
x + xy = (1\cdot x) + (y \cdot x) = (1 + y)\cdot x = x\,(y+1)
$$
In general, this is referred to as "factoring".  In this case, we "factored out" an $x$.